# Convert raw .audio file to .m4a

Tags: audio, conversion, audacity, m4a

I have some sound recordings I made but now, it is recovered as `.audio` file. So, I downloaded Audacity and I'm trying to convert it back to `.m4a`. But I have no idea what should I put in these fields:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why but image isn't being put here?

Comment: You don't give us enough information for a concise answer.  You say "it is recovered".. as if you recovered this from a crash.  If this is true, you might need to look at the header with a hex editor and figure out those fields "by hand".. it is a pain but very rewarding when you get it right! :)

Comment: Hi, as above. Not quite sure what this question is about exactly. If you're looking to recover a file and you are sure that it was `.m4a` then all you have to do is to change the extension to `.m4a`, as long as it's not corrupted. If you're looking to indeed convert it from that format to `.m4a` then you need to be more specific about how you made/got the file as `.audio` is not really a common sound extension.

Comment: What options have you tried in that dialog? Did any of them work or not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of Audacity, this dialog has a "detect" button that will make an educated guess on how the file is encoded.

NB: This dialog only works on uncompressed audio, ie actual raw data. It is entirely possible that your .audio file is an .mp3 in disguise or something else. If that's the case, you can use MediaInfo to find out what headers the file uses internally and rename the file to have the right extension.